# How to solve ODEs with constraints using BVP4C?

Tags: matlab, ode, boundary-conditions

I am using `BVP4C` to solve a system of ODEs which is as follows.
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} &- \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{x} f(x,y)\big) = \lambda \ddot{x}(s)\\
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} &- \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{y} f(x,y)\big) = \lambda \ddot{y}(s)\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

There is a constraint which is of the form
$$\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = 1$$.

The boundary conditions are 
$$x(0) = x_A, \, y(0) = y_A, \, x(l) = x_B, y(l) = y_B$$.

What should I do to deal with above constraint?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp Exchange. A better description of your problem is needed to provide you suggestions that are related to what you want. What is your system of equations?

Comment: @yagoo instead of commenting, please edit your question.  Also, please indicate what the boundary conditions are.

Comment: @yagoo: This system of equations doesn't look like a system of ODEs; rather, it looks like a system of PDEs. I suppose $s$ is supposed to be the "time" variable? Are you discretizing the PDEs in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Geoff Oxberry: It looks like a system of PDEs, however, it is a system of ODEs. As you said, $s$ is supposed to be the "time" variable.

Comment: So what is $f$? Is it a given function? Please describe all objects that you use.

Comment: @eriatarka84: Yes, $f$ is a given function

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a new unknown $\phi(s)$ such that
$$
  (\dot x(s), \dot y(s)) = (\cos\phi(s), \sin\phi(s)),
$$
then rewrite the problem as a system of coupled first-order ODEs. You now got rid of the constraint and can use any standard ODE integrator.

Comment: @yagoo, if this solve your problem why don't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You call this system an ODE ([ordinary differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)), but this sort of system is actually called an DAE ([differential algebraic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation)).

> What should I do to deal with above constraint?

The constraint $\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = 1$ is a smaller problem than the fact that you need to determine the time evolution of $\lambda$, or more precisely analytically compute the constraint satisfied by $\lambda$. One way to do this is to first write the system in integral form:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{x} (f(x,y)-\lambda)\big) &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{y} (f(x,y)-\lambda)\big) &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

and then introduce dummy variables for converting it into semi-explicit form:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{dx}{ds} &= \dot{x}\\
 \frac{dy}{ds} &= \dot{y}\\
 \frac{du}{ds} &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{dv}{ds} &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 u &= \dot{x} (f(x,y)-\lambda)\\
 v &= \dot{y} (f(x,y)-\lambda)\\
 1 &= \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

You are lucky that the algebraic equation system can be solved for $\dot{x}$, $\dot{y}$, and $\lambda$. In general, you must use [Pantelides algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantelides_algorithm) (for example) to generate more constraints (and dummy variables) until your original dynamic variables are uniquely determined by the constrains.

You don't even need $\lambda$, so let's eliminate it:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{y}u &= \dot{x}v\\
 1 &= \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

This algebraic equation system now allows you to compute $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ from $u$ and $v$. So `BVP4C` will only *see* $x$, $y$, $u$, and $v$, and you will solve for $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ yourself and use it where it is needed.

**Edit: Warning, the solution above is wrong!** Writing the system in integral form is not as straightforward as suggested, because we actually have

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{x} f(x,y)\big)-\lambda\frac{d}{ds}\dot{x} &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\\
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{y} f(x,y)\big)-\lambda\frac{d}{ds}\dot{y} &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

We could introduce dummy variables $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{y}$ to get an integral form

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{x} f(x,y)\big) &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+\lambda\ddot{x}\\
 \frac{d}{ds}\big(\dot{y} f(x,y)\big) &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}+\lambda\ddot{y}\\
 \frac{d}{ds}\dot{x} &= \ddot{x}\\
 \frac{d}{ds}\dot{y} &= \ddot{y}\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

And now we really need to apply Pantelides algorithm...

Comment: @yagoo I just noticed that my answer is wrong. The transformation to integral form omitted a term involving a derivative of $\lambda$. This probably means that the index of the system is bigger than one, which will require some mastery of the techniques to solve.